# Airflow examples without dates

Tags: python, airflow

I am new to using [airflow](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/index.html).  I am trying to run a dag and don't want to do any scheduling.

I would like to run the pipeline with a command line argument and override all of the current output.  I have no start date, no scheduling, no timing, and no retry logic, I just want to run a set of functions sequentially to get started.

The documentation always includes a date.

```
airflow test tutorial print_date 2015-06-01
```

I want to run the dag so that it executes all functions and ignores any previous runs.  How do I remove all dates and date logic from my dag?

I have a modified version of the tutorial dag file:

```
"""
Code that goes along with the Airflow tutorial located at:
https://github.com/airbnb/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py
"""
import os
import cPickle
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'schedule_interval': '@once'
}

dag = DAG('tutorial_me', default_args=default_args)

def save_file(filenm):
    with open(filenm, 'wb') as pickle_file:
        cPickle.dump(['1','2',3], pickle_file)

def delete_file(filenm):
    print "************ THIS IS WHERE STDOUT GOES"
    if os.path.exists(filenm):
        os.path.remove(filenm)


# t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='save_file',
    python_callable=save_file,
    op_kwargs=dict(filenm='__myparamfile__.txt'),
    dag=dag)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='remove_file',
    python_callable=delete_file,
    op_kwargs=dict(filenm='__myparamfile__.txt'),
    dag=dag)

t1.set_upstream(t2)
```

The first time that I run it with:

```
airflow run tutorial_me remove_file 2015-01-04
```

It works and prints the `print "************ THIS IS WHERE STDOUT GOES"` line.  The second time I run it, it does not.

The log file looks something like this after the second run

```
cat 2015-01-04T00\:00\:00
[2016-12-10 11:27:47,158] {models.py:154} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/user_01/airflow/dags
[2016-12-10 11:27:47,214] {models.py:1750} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(PythonOperator): save_file>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2016-12-10 11:27:47,214] {models.py:1750} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(PythonOperator): remove_file>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2016-12-10 11:27:47,227] {base_executor.py:36} INFO - Adding to queue: airflow run tutorial_me remove_file 2015-01-04T00:00:00 --local -sd DAGS_FOLDER/tutorial_01.py
[2016-12-10 11:27:47,234] {sequential_executor.py:26} INFO - Executing command: airflow run tutorial_me remove_file 2015-01-04T00:00:00 --local -sd DAGS_FOLDER/tutorial_01.py
[2016-12-10 11:27:48,050] {models.py:154} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/user_01/airflow/dags/tutorial_01.py
[2016-12-10 11:27:48,101] {models.py:1750} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(PythonOperator): save_file>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2016-12-10 11:27:48,102] {models.py:1750} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(PythonOperator): remove_file>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2016-12-10 11:27:48,942] {models.py:154} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/user_01/airflow/dags/tutorial_01.py
[2016-12-10 11:27:48,998] {models.py:1750} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(PythonOperator): save_file>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2016-12-10 11:27:48,998] {models.py:1750} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(PythonOperator): remove_file>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2016-12-10 11:27:49,020] {models.py:1196} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 1 of 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2016-12-10 11:27:49,046] {models.py:1219} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): remove_file> on 2015-01-04 00:00:00
[2016-12-10 11:27:49,054] {python_operator.py:67} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
[2016-12-10 11:27:55,168] {models.py:154} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/user_01/airflow/dags
[2016-12-10 11:27:55,219] {models.py:1750} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(PythonOperator): save_file>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2016-12-10 11:27:55,220] {models.py:1750} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(PythonOperator): remove_file>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2016-12-10 11:27:55,231] {base_executor.py:36} INFO - Adding to queue: airflow run tutorial_me remove_file 2015-01-04T00:00:00 --local -sd DAGS_FOLDER/tutorial_01.py
[2016-12-10 11:27:55,236] {sequential_executor.py:26} INFO - Executing command: airflow run tutorial_me remove_file 2015-01-04T00:00:00 --local -sd DAGS_FOLDER/tutorial_01.py
[2016-12-10 11:27:56,030] {models.py:154} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/user_01/airflow/dags/tutorial_01.py
[2016-12-10 11:27:56,082] {models.py:1750} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(PythonOperator): save_file>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2016-12-10 11:27:56,082] {models.py:1750} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(PythonOperator): remove_file>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2016-12-10 11:27:56,899] {models.py:154} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/user_01/airflow/dags/tutorial_01.py
[2016-12-10 11:27:56,950] {models.py:1750} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(PythonOperator): save_file>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2016-12-10 11:27:56,951] {models.py:1750} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(PythonOperator): remove_file>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2016-12-10 11:27:56,967] {models.py:1150} INFO -
```

Comment: You may have given a bit too much data, and scared away the locals. Can you reword your question along the suggestions of [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow is designed to maintain a history of its DAG runs so it can process batches of data in order and ensure each task runs exactly once for its DagRun.

For what you're trying to do the simplest would probably be to ignore the scheduler and externally trigger a DagRun with an execution date of "now", including the full date and time.  This ensures that each run you invoke executes all tasks exactly once, and that each run of a task is independent of any previous runs.  You will need depends_on_past = False and you may also need max_active_runs to be some very large value, as any failed DagRuns will remain "active" but you don't want them to interfere with new invocations.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your request is similar to [airflow issue #198](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-198):

> "For cases where we need to only run the latest in a series of task instance runs and mark the others as skipped. For example, we may have job to execute a DB snapshot every day. If the DAG is paused for 5 days and then unpaused, we don’t want to run all 5, just the latest. With this feature, we will provide “cron” functionality for task scheduling that is not related to ETL"

This issue has been addressed with the `LatestOnlyOperator` feature as documented [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/1752).

Usage is described in the official docs at https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#latest-run-only

```
from airflow.operators.latest_only_operator import LatestOnlyOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='latest_only_with_trigger',
    schedule_interval=dt.timedelta(hours=4),
    start_date=dt.datetime(2016, 9, 20),
)

latest_only = LatestOnlyOperator(task_id='latest_only', dag=dag)
```